# Function not being bind at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to avoid my page being refreshed after submitting my form. In order to do this I've added into my javascript section

```
$("body").on('click',"#register",new_user_pop);
$("body").on('click',"#screen",pop_out);
$("body").on('click',"#new-user",pop_registration);

$('form[name=new-user-form]').on('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    alert("Not refreshing");
```

The function works properly as in order to debug it I pasted it on the Terminal from the Chrome's developer tools and it started working.
But for some reason I do not know it does not work it does not get loads at the beginning.
The previous function $("body").on('click')... work all fine.

Comment: You should also cache your `$("body")` query into a variable then add the `on()` events to that. Each time you use $() it results in the query being re-run.

Comment: What do you mean by "the query bein re-run"? Extra processing effort to detrmine which is the body element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your code runs *after* you've defined the HTML elements you want to attach your events to.

You can either do this by placing your script below the HTML bit you need.

Or you can wrap your code in an onready/load callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* code goes here */
});
```

Comment: This is not the prefered way to bind `ready`. Either do `$(document).ready(...)` or `$(...)`. Reason: the latter two are not "normal" events, and fire their handlers immediately when bound after the event has fired

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
But, does this means that from now on each binding I would like to do I will need to put it under $(document).on(...?

Comment: No. You need to wrap your JQuery code in a ready() function, this just waits until the dom is loaded, it isn't an issue of scope.